# Symfony: Error with File Constraint

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

```
->add('shots','file', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    **'constraints' => array(
        new Constraints\Image(array(
            'maxSize' => '10M',
            'allowSquare' => false,
            'allowPortrait' => false,
            'minRatio' => 1.43,
            'maxRatio' => 2.4
        )),
    )**
))
```

This is part of a symfony form with intgrated form validator. But I get an error I dont understand:

```
UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument of type "string", "array" given
```

Without the **marked part** everthing does work. I checked the reference of the form constraints, but I didn't get the solution ...

Comment: could you provide stack trace of your exception?

Comment: @barius how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\FileValidator` that throw you this exception.
Expecting your form value to be something that can be casted into string, but got array...

You should try to use the All constraint as a surrounding constraint of File, like this :

```
->add('shots','file', array(
    'multiple'    => true,
    'constraints' => array(
        new All(array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new Image(array(
                    'maxSize'       => '10M',
                    'allowSquare'   => false,
                    'allowPortrait' => false,
                    'minRatio'      => 1.43,
                    'maxRatio'      => 2.4
                ))
            )
        ))
    ))
))
```

See http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html

Comment: hey, this does works! But I am not amazed of this solution ... have so better suggestions? And I didn't really understand, why my try generates an error?!

Comment: This is because your are using a "multiple file uploader". So your value will logically be an array of File. But the constraint you set don't know how to process array values (as it throw an exception). The constraint All as been created to wrap other constraint when dealing with arrays or collection of values

Comment: I think it should also work with initial setup, after changing `multiple` to `false`.

Comment: @barius sure, but that is against the intention of validating multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image;
...
...
...
->add('shots','file', array(
    'multiple'    => true,
    'constraints' => array(
        new Image(array(
            'maxSize'       => '10M',
            'allowSquare'   => false,
            'allowPortrait' => false,
            'minRatio'      => 1.43,
            'maxRatio'      => 2.4
        )),
    )
))
```

Comment: why should that change something? I did: ´use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Constraints´, so I only choosed a shorter way ...