# Symfony2 / File - File Validation

Tags: file, validation, symfony

I try to validate file, befor upload, but I doing something wrong.

This is my file in form type:

```
->add('file', 'file', array(
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '5M',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/*'
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Only images allowed!'
                    ])
                ],
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
                'data_class' => null,
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'maxSize' => '1024k',
                    'accept' => 'image/*',
                )
            ))
```

If I select .txt, .php, ... to upload, so it's normally uploaded, without errors.

How to make it work?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

My Upload Function:

```
private function uploadImg($files)
    {
        $path = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $extension = $file->guessExtension();
            if (!$extension) {
                $extension = 'bin';
            }
            $randomName = 'image' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('uploads/images/', $randomName);
            $path[] = $randomName;
        }
        return $path;
    }
```

and in controller:

`$ads->setPath(implode(',', $this->uploadImg($form['file']->getData())));`

Comment: according to docs, there is no attr `constraints` in file field type http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html

Comment: hmm, If I look on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983521/symfony-error-with-file-constraint) i see file and constraints, how can I do it now?

Comment: better to use annotations constraints for entity, inside entity you can use http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html. If you have only form without entity, better create model class for represent form data, if it unclear I can give example to you

Comment: No I don't have entity for this form. I tried to create entity, but I have multiple upload, and symfony2 showed me error `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to DbBundle\Entity\Ads::setFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, array given` Here is my set function `public function setFile(File $f = null){ foreach ($f as $files) { $this->file = $files; } }`

Comment: just for info, you just want to upload files to server? what fields consists in your form? error  is expectable because you should pass single file to setFile, but you have array of files, and you need to handle that array

Comment: I want to upload file to server and write all file names to the cell in database. 
I tried create upload like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), but it isn't work for multiple upload, and I didn't find solution for this issue. 

But I created my own upload function -> main question edited.

Comment: If it works good. I cant say anythyng because I dont know your entire aimm so sorry, once I implement multiple upload and I was create separate entity for each image and then turn each image from array to that entity

Comment: Do you validate form in your controller before calling the uploadImg function?

Comment: `if($form->isValid()){
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$validator->validate($ads);
}` ? sure